# WPF Application - releasing strategy

Tags: c#, wpf, azure-devops, clickonce, canary-deployment

I'm seeking some advice about improving our release strategy for an inhouse WPF application.
Currently, we are using ClickOnce to release new versions to our users.
Still manual, but we are looking into using DevOps pipelines to streamline this.

We have noticed that, as our application grows, we are getting more risks of making some breaking changes without noticing it during the testing phase. We have a small team and tight deadlines, so testing phase is limited.
So, to improve our way of working we were investigating canary releases. This would imply that we first release new version to a set of key-users and when they don't notice any issues, we would launch it for everybody.

From an application perspective, I could make it work. But I'm not sure how we can make this work with our database.

Has anyone tried this approach with desktop applications already? Or are there better ways to do this kind of thing?

Any help is appreciated!

Kind Regards
Tim

Comment: Jenkins may help in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have integrated a two step release pipeline for this same purpose.  We have an internal UAT stage that pushes out the app internally, via Microsoft's AppCenter, and then a second full release stage which publish to "production".

We're not using ClickOnce, but the principle is the same. You could have an UAT and Production publish locations for each stage.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned. We have a test and live version that gets deployed via ClickOnce. Things are validated in the test version, but not everything. That's why we are searching for a way to limit the impact of deploying a new live version.